# javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

How do you write a JS regular expression to extract the first "2" from `"/?page=2&promo_id=1234`". (ie page number 2)

Thanks!

Comment: Start here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var extractPageNumber = function(s) {
  var r=/page=(\d+)/, m=(""+s).match(r);
  return (m) ? Number(m[1]) : undefined;
};
extractPageNumber("/?page=2&promo_id=1234"); // => 2
extractPageNumber("/?page=321&promo_id=1234"); // => 321
extractPageNumber("foobar"); // => undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

```
var match = /page=(\d+)/.exec("/?page=2&promo_id=1234"), pageNum = match[1];
```

Comment: I wrote a solution very close to yours, but they had both the same issue: if it doesn't match (say, because there is no number), JS will try to read the 2nd element of a null-value, and crash…

Comment: that's quite context specific but `|| undefined` at the end should work it out.

Answer (score 1):

It depend on what may vary in your string. If the number is the only variable, then:

```
var match, pageNumber;
if(pageNumber = "/?page=2&promo_id=1234".match(/page=(\d+)/))
    pageNumber = match[1];
```

Or the ugly (but shorter) way

```
var pageNumber = ("/?page=223&promo_id=a".match(/page=(\d+)/)||[,undefined])[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use regular expressions as such, I'd use the `split` method:

```
var str="/?page=2&promo_id=1234";

document.write(str.split("/?page=")[1][0]);
```

Of course this will only work for single digit numbers.  You could modify it to work for all numbers using a proper regular expression.

http://jsfiddle.net/u8ZXc/